# Nested stored procedure, setting variable to output/result

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2 I'm currently running a stored procedure, inside of which I'm calling another stored procedure with a parameter.

```
P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE V_ID INTEGER ;

CALL PROGRAMS. GET_ID_BY_NAME(P_NAME) ;

-- need output of above procedure to be set to V_ID for another call here

END P1
```

How can I set the result of that call to the variable V_ID so that I can use it down the line?

Comment: What do you mean by “result of that call”? Do you want to get a value of the `RETURN` statement called inside the inner procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship between ID and NAME is 1:1 , or if you simply don't care which matching name gets returned, then it is easier to modify the stored procedure (or create a renamed clone of the stored-procedure and modify the cloned copy) so that the stored procedure has an OUTPUT parameter, which the stored procedure can simply `SET` to the matching name, and on return the caller stored-procedure simply uses that variable name to access its value.

You may want to defensively code for a no match by arranging that the output parameter is set to NULL for that case, and test for that in the calling code.  There are plenty of examples of using stored-procedure output parameters if you search, either the official Db2 documentation or elsewhere.

Using an output-parameter from the stored procedure (instead of a result-set) is the simplest approach, fewer lines of code.

Otherwise, if the relationship between ID and NAME is 1:n, and the caller wants to choose which match, then the called-stored procedure should return a result set (0 or more rows ) via an open `WITH RETURN` cursor. Your caller code would need to handle both the 0 rows returned case, and choose which row to use (if more than one row is returned) if you want to choose between them (usually on the basis of another column in the result-set).

To access the result-set of a called stored-procedure from inside the caller procedure, your caller procedure needs to use statements like these `[ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR][1] (v1) WITH PROCEDURE PROGRAMS.GET_ID_BY_NAME`, after the `CALL PROGRAMS.GET_ID_BY_NAME()`, then `[ALLOCATE c1 CURSOR FOR RESULT SET][1] v1`.

You now have a cursor which you can iterate over to `FETCH` each row into variables, and at end you must `CLOSE` the cursor. If you know there is only ever be a single row in the result set then you don't need to iterate.

If you search, there are plenty of examples of these statements, including in the IBM documentation for your Db2 version and platform. I have shown links for Db2-LUW.